# Solving limits without L'hospitals Rule

Tags: limits

Thanks for helping me out with the last question :) Unfortunately there was a typo in the second question...

It's actually $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{3^\frac1x-1}{3^\frac1x+1}$

Should I start off the solution by letting $t$ (or a certain variable) $= \dfrac1x+1$ (which is the power of the denominator?

Comment: That is what I found the limit of in my answer. The typo occurred *after* I had answered.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\dfrac1x=h$ to convert the limit to $$F=\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{3^h-1}{3^h+1}$$

For $h>0,$
$$F=\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{1-(1/3)^h}{1+(1/3)^h}$$

Now $\lim_{h\to\infty}r^h=0$ if $|r|<1$

What if $h<0$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks, I really missed that

Answer (score 0):

Easier: when $x \to 0, \ 3^{\frac{1}{x}} \to \infty$, hence the expression becomes $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t-1}{t+1} = 1 - \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{2}{t+1}$, which you can easilty take.